# C++ Partial Specialization Not Working for Differing Size Eigen Matrices

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, metaprogramming, eigen

I've been banging my head into a wall for the last couple of hours trying to figure out why some partial template specializations are failing, and I could really use some help.

Basically, I'm working on some code that relies on knowing the sizes of matrices at compile time, but I'm trying to do it generically with templates. There seems to be some kind of issue with using type compositions that I really don't understand. By way of illustration, consider the following (slightly pointless) code:

```
template <typename T> struct type1 { typedef bool bar; };
template <typename T, int R, int C> struct type1<Matrix<T, R, C>> { typedef Matrix<T, R, C> bar; };

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct type2 { typedef bool bar; };
template <typename T, int R, int M, int C> struct type2<Matrix<T, R, M>, Matrix<T, M, C>> { typedef Matrix<float, 2, 2> bar; };

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct type3 { typedef bool bar; };
template <typename T, int R, int M, int C> struct type3<Matrix<T, R, M>, Matrix<T, M, C>> { typedef Matrix<T, R, C> bar; };

template <typename T> struct Test {
    static bool foo() {
        return false;
    }
};
template <typename T, int R, int C> struct Test<Matrix<T, R, C>> {
    static bool foo() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

My understanding of template composition is that these templates should be able to be composed in ways like the below where every line should return true. Note, however, that the last two return false.

```
/* true  <- */  Test<Matrix<float, 2, 2>>::foo();
/* true  <- */  Test<Matrix<float, 6, 3>>::foo();
/* true  <- */  Test<type1<Matrix<float, 2, 7>>::bar>::foo();
/* And so on for any other size . . . */

/* true  <- */  Test<type2<Matrix<float, 3, 3>, Matrix<float, 3, 3>>::bar>::foo();
/* true  <- */  Test<type3<Matrix<float, 2, 2>, Matrix<float, 2, 2>>::bar>::foo();
/* And so on for any other pair of square sizes . . . */

/* false <- */  Test<type2<Matrix<float, 2, 3>, Matrix<float, 3, 2>>::bar>::foo();
/* false <- */  Test<type3<Matrix<float, 2, 4>, Matrix<float, 4, 1>>::bar>::foo();
/* And so on for any other pair of non-square sizes . . . */
```

What's especially weird is that when I replace `Eigen::Matrix` with an arbitrary `template <typename T, int R, int C> struct Thing` everything works as expected (ie. all tests return true), which is why I think this problem is specific to Eigen Matrices.

---

**Edit**: Actually, this seems to be tied to the fact that I'm building on MSVC (fails identically on both 2015 and 2017). When I compile this on either g++ or clang, it works fine. More evidence that visual c++ is a real mess (not that it's really needed).

Furthermore, it seems to actually be tied to cases where the two parameters have differing sizes. For example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct typetest { typedef bool bar; };
template <typename T, int R1, int C1, int R2, int C2> struct typetest<Matrix<T, R1, C1>, Matrix<T, R2, C2>> { typedef Matrix<float, 2, 2> bar; };
```

This succeeds when first and second matrix types have the same size, but fails when they differ. For example:

```
/* true  <- */  Test<typetest<Matrix<float, 2, 3>, Matrix<float, 2, 3>>::bar>::foo();
/* true  <- */  Test<typetest<Matrix<float, 6, 1>, Matrix<float, 6, 1>>::bar>::foo();
/* false <- */  Test<typetest<Matrix<float, 2, 2>, Matrix<float, 2, 3>>::bar>::foo();
/* false <- */  Test<typetest<Matrix<float, 5, 3>, Matrix<float, 2, 4>>::bar>::foo();
```

Unfortunately, I'm mostly stuck with MSVC for the time being, owing to some very annoying dependencies, so I need a workaround. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Everything works for me (no false values) with Eigen::Matrix. I can give a screenshot.

Comment: I used the newest 3.3.4 by the way.

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: There is no error message. It compiles and runs without any errors, but the results are wrong. The results from g++/clang conform to C++11, while those from MSVC do not.

Comment: If you found a case where the compiler is broken, **report it to Microsoft** with your test case.

Comment: Already reported, see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94492/c-partial-specialization-fails-when-eigen-matrices.html)

Comment: As a workaround, did you try `template <typename T, int R, int C, int O, int Rc, int Cc> struct Test<Matrix<T, R, C, O, Rc, Cc>> {...`, i.e., adding the optional/implicit template parameters of `Eigen::Matrix`? (I don't have MSVC, so I can't test this)

Comment: I strongly recommend trying chtz suggestion which is very likely to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it complete, the solution suggested by @chtz in the comments above totally works with MSVC 2015 and 2017. By way of an example for the specific differing size issue from the question, this works perfectly:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct typen { typedef bool bar; };
template <typename T, int R, int M, int C, int O1, int O2, int Rc1, int Rc2, int Cc1, int Cc2>
    struct typen<Matrix<T, R, M, O1, Rc1, Cc1>, Matrix<T, M, C, O2, Rc2, Cc2>> { typedef Matrix<T, R, C> bar; };
...
/* true :-) */  Test<typen<Matrix<float, 2, 3>, Matrix<float, 3, 4>>::bar>::foo();
```